# ScalaJS Uncaught TypeError: $g.require is not a function

Tags: scala.js

Source code for reference is [here](https://github.com/avidanyum/scalajs-example)

When I access `http://localhost:12345/target/scala-2.11/classes/index-dev.html`

```
Uncaught TypeError: $g.require is not a function$c_Lexample_ScalaJSExample$.main__Lorg_scalajs_dom_raw_HTMLCanvasElement__V @ ScalaJSExample.scala:22$c_Lexample_ScalaJSExample$.$$js$exported$meth$main__Lorg_scalajs_dom_raw_HTMLCanvasElement__O @ ScalaJSExample.scala:21$c_Lexample_ScalaJSExample$.main @ ScalaJSExample.scala:21(anonymous function) @ VM242:1(anonymous function) @ workbench.js:63
```

Funnel.scala

```
package example

import scala.scalajs.js

@js.native
trait Funnel extends js.Object {
  def draw(values: js.Array[js.Array[Any]], options: js.Object): Unit = js.native
}
```

ScalaJSExample.scala:

```
package example

import scala.scalajs.js.Object
import scala.scalajs.js.annotation.JSExport
import org.scalajs.dom
import org.scalajs.dom.html
import scala.util.Random
import scala.scalajs.js
import js.Dynamic.{global => g}
import js.DynamicImplicits._


case class Point(x: Int, y: Int){
  def +(p: Point) = Point(x + p.x, y + p.y)
  def /(d: Int) = Point(x / d, y / d)
}

@JSExport
object ScalaJSExample {

  @JSExport
  def main(canvas: html.Canvas): Unit = {
    val ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
      .asInstanceOf[dom.CanvasRenderingContext2D]

    val Funnel = js.Dynamic.global.require("d3-funnel")
    val chart = js.Dynamic.newInstance(Funnel)("#funnel").asInstanceOf[Funnel]

    val data = js.Array(js.Array("Plants", 5000))
    val options = new Object()

    chart.draw(data, options)

    var count = 0
    var p = Point(0, 0)
    val corners = Seq(Point(255, 255), Point(0, 255), Point(128, 0))

    def clear() = {
      ctx.fillStyle = "black"
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 255, 255)
    }

    def run = for (i <- 0 until 10){
      if (count % 3000 == 0) clear()
      count += 1
      p = (p + corners(Random.nextInt(3))) / 2

      val height = 512.0 / (255 + p.y)
      val r = (p.x * height).toInt
      val g = ((255-p.x) * height).toInt
      val b = p.y
      ctx.fillStyle = s"rgb($g, $r, $b)"

      ctx.fillRect(p.x, p.y, 1, 1)
    }

    dom.setInterval(() => run, 50)
  }
}
```

Comment: If you don't include `require.js` anywhere (e.g., in your HTML file), it won't be able to find `require`.

Comment: I included with `jsDependencies += "org.webjars" % "requirejs" % "2.1.22" / "require.js"` and still have this shouldn't it be enough to include it in `sbt`?

Comment: No, that's not enough. Have a look at the section "Adding JavaScript libraries" of https://www.scala-js.org/tutorial/basic/ to see how to bring that dependency to your html file.

Comment: The tutorial says to bring it from `target` directory after running `fastOptJS` I ran `fastOptJS` but I don't see `require.js` in `target` the only place I see it in is in `.ivy/....` am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Do you have `skip in packageJSDependencies := false`?

Comment: added now.. :/ passed this stage, I get now `Uncaught Error: Module name "d3-funnel" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])` , sources here: https://github.com/avidanyum/scalajs-example